# Convert to virtualenv an existing project by copying site-packages

Tags: python

I have an old Django project that I want to convert to use virtualenv. If I could copy the current global Python packages to the new env, I think I'd be assured that I'd have the same environment and would save myself some time over creating a requirements file by hand. So, could I just copy the global site-packages contents into the env's site-packages directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Python packages often have filesystem paths written to various metadata files. Just take the time to go through the site-packages and install the things into a fresh virtualenv, then call pip freeze to get a serialized list that you can use going forward.

Comment: This is doubly true if the env is on the same box as the site-packages - and it sounds like it is. There's going to be .pth files and .egg-infos that reference the global paths. sys.path hell imo.

Comment: Haven't verified @AdamKG's answer but don't doubt it. I realized that pip freeze from the start to get the globally-installed packages is a helpful approach.